# How do I create an ipip tunnel between two hosts on a LAN?

Tags: linux, networking, tunneling

I have two hosts on a LAN. Both hosts have static IPv4 addresses.

```
Host1: eth0: 112.92.0.1
Host2: eth0: 112.92.0.3
```

I now want to create an ipip tunnel between these two hosts such that any packet sent to the tunnel interface on one host is automatically forwarded to the tunnel interface on the other host. I am working on RHL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out **OpenVPN** or some *IPsec* implementations like **Openswan**.

Comment: Can you me to some article/tutorial which talks about how to solve my problem.

Comment: For IPsec: http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch35_:_Configuring_Linux_VPNs

Comment: And for OpenVPN: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html